# Volume of a submanifold compared to manifolds volume

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, submanifold

Assume I have a manifold $M$ with $dim(M) = m$. The manifold is equipped with a coordinate chart $x_{i}$ such that the given metric on the manifold is:

$g_{ij} = \delta_{ij} + \frac{x_{i}x_{j}}{1-\sum_{k}x^{2}_{k}}$ and the coordinates satisfy $\sum_{k}x^{2}_{k}\leq1$.

The manifold has a finite volume that can be calculated in the chart as:

$V = \int_{\sum_{k}x^{2}_{k}\leq1} \sqrt{|g|}dx$

Assume I have a submanifold $N$ embedded in $M$ which is defined by the parameterization:

$x_{i} = \sum_{j}A_{ij}\theta_{j}$ with $A\in \mathbb{R}^{[mXn]}$ and $n<m$ is the dimension of the submanifold

As far as I understand, the induced metric on the submanifold is:

$\tilde{g}_{ij}=\sum_{kl}A^{T}_{ik}g_{kl}A_{lj}$

and the volume of the submanifold is

$\tilde{V} = \int_{\sum_{k}x^{2}_{k}\leq1} \sqrt{|\tilde{g}|}d\theta$

My intuition tells me that since the submanifold is embedded in the original manifold its volume should be in some sense smaller than the original manifolds volume (i.e $\tilde{V}<V$). Numerically evaluating the integrals for a specific $A$ I get that it is wrong in general. I'm trying to figure out wether there is a problem with my code or math and I suspect that my problem is with the math side of things, so I have two questions:

1.Is it true that $\tilde{V}<V$ in the general case or even in my specific case? I understand that in some sense I am comparing volumes of different dimensions so it might be nonsense.

2.Is there a sense in which I can get an $m$ dimensional volume characterizing the submanifold $N$, which is comparable to $V$ and smaller than $V$, in the sense that "we are only counting part of the manifold"?

Something like $\int_{U}\sqrt{|g|}dx \ \ \  U=\{x|\exists \theta \ \ s.t \ \ x=A\theta \}$. Is it possible to represent this integral as integration over the parameters $\theta$?

if so I'd be glad to get a reference for the relevant information.

Comment: (1) is not true in general: the volume of $(0, 1)$ is bigger than the volume of $(0, 1)\times(0, \frac{1}{2})$, we may glue the boundary to get an example of a pair of compact manifolds.

Comment: By the Nash-Kuiper embedding theorem, any compact manifold embeds isometrically in a ball of radius $\varepsilon$ in some large euclidean space, so you can find submanifolds with volume as large as you want in balls as small as you want

Comment: Also: I am not sure about your equality on $\bar V$: the domain of the integral seems to be the same as that of $V$, which cannot be since the two manifolds are not parametrized by the same set

Comment: Answering @Didier : The domain is defined as all $\theta$ such that $\vec{x}(\theta)=A\vec{\theta}$ satisfies the condition.